# Can (or should) "prevalent" be gradable?

Tags: writing-style, logic, gradability

Well, that's all. Can it?

Is it not illogical to say that something is "more prevalent"? Is "prevalent" not, by definition, superlative? Is it not like saying that something is "more best"?

Comment: More prevalent: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more%20prevalent%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: No, _prevalent_ is not a superlative.

Comment: Sure. Of course. I know. But... isn't it illogical? I may have misspoken. SHOULD it be gradable?

Comment: "Should it be gradable?" asks for an opinion-based answer..

Comment: What is the definition of the word??

Comment: Jules, perhaps using the noun "prevalence" rather than the adjective "prevalent" would be better than "more best"

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prevalent): _prevalent_ adjective: ... 
1: generally or widely accepted, practiced, or favored : WIDESPREAD // 
2: being in ascendancy : DOMINANT // 
3 [archaic] : POWERFUL. More widespread? More widely accepted? More generally favoured? More dominant? [Most powerful?] _Illogical_? //// [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prevalent): _prevalent_ (comparative more prevalent, superlative most prevalent) ... _Is it gradable?_?

Comment: Ask yourself, of two things that are 'prevalent', can you compare the degree of prevalence? Does "X is prevalent" mean "X appears often" or "X appears absolutely everywhere"? If something is absolute, like 'unique' or 'entire', then it is not gradable, not comparable.

Comment: If you are going to answer the question in the comments, why not just write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not illogical. According to Cambridge online dictionary, "prevalent" means:

"existing very commonly or happening often".

See the two examples they give here:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/prevalent

Some disease might be more prevalent in one country than in another--in other words, it might be more widespread. That seems to be a very relevant example right now :)